# filter the properties of an object based on an array. And get the filtered object

Tags: javascript, filter

how can i filter the properties of an object based on an array. I have sample snippet below.

```js
var obj = {a: [], b:[], c: [], d:[]}
var arr = ["a", "b"]
```

Following is my expected output, how can i achieve this

> var outupt = {a: [], b:[]}

Comment: You will have to map `arr` with `obj` and then you can get required output

Comment: got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {a: [], b:[], c: [], d:[]}
var arr = ["a", "b"]

var output = arr.reduce((result, key) => ({ ...result, [key]: obj[key] }), {});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map new objects and create a single object.

```js
var object = { a: [], b: [], c: [], d: [] },
    keys = ["a", "b"],
    result = Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] })));

console.log(result);
```